# Bash: string of variables as program options

Tags: bash

My program takes three options `./program a b c INPUT > OUTPUT` (`a`,`b`,`c` are options).
I have a list of option combinations:

```
cat list_of_combinations
1 2 3
4 8 3 
1 5 7
9 5 6
```

I want to execute `program` using those four different combinations. For example:

```
./program 1 2 3 INPUT >> OUTPUT  
./program 4 8 3 INPUT >> OUTPUT
./program 1 5 7 INPUT >> OUTPUT
```

---

I already tried this:

```
while read COMBO; do
    echo $COMBO | 
     ./program - INPUT >> OUTPUT
done < list_of_combinations
```

And this:

```
while read COMBO; do
    ./program $COMBO INPUT >> OUTPUT
done < list_of_combinations
```

---

My question is:
How to execute program/command while using a string of variables as options?

**Edit**

I wouldn't have any problems if there was only one character as variable. What I mean by that:
Program takes only one option:

```
./program a INPUT > OUTPUT
cat VARIABLES
    1 
    15
    78
while read VARIABLE; do
    ./program $VARIABLE INPUT > OUTPUT
done < VARIABLES
```

But when there are several options (string of characters), for example `./program a b INPUT > OUTPUT` I am getting error.

Comment: How are you getting `list_of_combinations`?

Comment: Your second loop with `./program $COMBO INPUT >> OUTPUT` should work as long as the arguments cannot themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes around your argument variable:

```
while read COMBO; do
    ./program "$COMBO" INPUT >> OUTPUT
done < list_of_combinations
```

Without quotes `$COMBO` will be considered 3 different inputs rather one single string as with the quotes.

Comment: When @Pgibas said that it should work like `./program 1 2 3 INPUT >> OUTPUT`, I assumed he meant that those commands actually worked when typed literally. :\

Answer (score 1):

By putting the options on the command line:

`./program $COMBO INPUT >> OUTPUT`

So your second example should work.  What goes wrong with it?

Comment: I already tried that (check my question). This would work it there was only one character as variable.

Comment: As I said above, what goes wrong?  What do you mean "This would work it there was only one character as variable"?